# Parsing json string into array

Tags: php, json

I want to parse JSON string so that I can get it saved into two dimensional array like shown below. Only solution I come with consist of 3 or 4 foreach loops, and I don't think that's good.

```
 {
  "root": {
    "row": [
      {
        "Status": "Enabled",
        "Keyword": "Toaletna voda",
        "Campaign": "Lešenari",
        "Adgroup": "Lešenaris",
        "BidStrategyType": "InheritFromParent",
        "Bid": "0.05",
        "Matchtype": "Broad",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Enabled",
        "Keyword": "lyžička",
        "Campaign": "Lešenari",
        "Adgroup": "Lešenaris",
        "BidStrategyType": "InheritFromParent",
        "Bid": "0.05",
        "Matchtype": "Broad",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Search total",
        "Keyword": "-",
        "Campaign": "-",
        "Adgroup": "-",
        "BidStrategyType": "-",
        "Bid": "-",
        "Matchtype": "-",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Content total",
        "Keyword": "-",
        "Campaign": "-",
        "Adgroup": "-",
        "BidStrategyType": "-",
        "Bid": "-",
        "Matchtype": "-",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Deleted items total",
        "Keyword": "-",
        "Campaign": "-",
        "Adgroup": "-",
        "BidStrategyType": "-",
        "Bid": "-",
        "Matchtype": "-",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Overall total",
        "Keyword": "-",
        "Campaign": "-",
        "Adgroup": "-",
        "BidStrategyType": "-",
        "Bid": "-",
        "Matchtype": "-",
        "Clicks": "0",
        "Impr.": "0",
        "Conv.": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It Should return something like this

```
Keyword=>Toaletna voda
Keyword=>lyžička
Campaign=>Lešenari
Campaign=>Lešenari
Adgroup=>Lešenaris
Adgroup=>Lešenaris
Bid=>0.05
Bid=>0.05
Clicks=>0
Clicks=>0
Impr.=>0
Impr.=>0
Conv.=>0
Conv.=>0
```

It should do same thing as this function, it takes array of names, and find values that are append to it in that xml file

```
public function LoadXmlReport($adSystemColumns = array())
    {
        require "config.php";

        $xmlfile = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__) . "/xmlfile.xml");
        foreach ($xmlfile as $key => $value)
            foreach ($value as $columnName => $item) {
                if ($item == "-") {
                    break;
                } elseif (array_search($columnName, $bing) !== FALSE)
                    $this->report[$columnName][] = $item;
            }

        foreach ($this->report as $key => $value)
            foreach ($value as $index => $item)
                echo $key."=>".$item."<br/>";
    }
```

those are the values

```
$bing = array(
"Adgroup",
"Campaign",
"Keyword",
"Clicks",
"Impr.",
"Conv.",
"Bid",
"Adgroup"
);
```

Comment: How about http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ?

Comment: Okay, the question is probably incorrectly formulated. I used json_decode, but then I got something that need like 3 or 4 nested foreach loops, and I need help with that.

Comment: Your desired output is still unclear. Is it dictionary with multiple same keys or arrays of pairs?

Comment: Probably Dictionary with multiple same keys. For example I have an excel file, one cell has name `Keyword` so I want value of every cell below assign to `array["Keyword"][]`. And actually, i have working method for csv format, but when i am looking on my xml method I am not sure it is possible, because if the xml file is nested one more time then I need another loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($json, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[$key][] = $value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a interesting function, we will see If I can come with some working code.